# mongo: converting a row oriented collection, to a column oriented collections

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Suppose I have:

- a large collection A, containing a large number of documents each made of the same row of large number of fields (eg. 10^8 rows x 300 fields)
- we want to convert it into 300 collections each containing only one large array of values (300 arrays x 10^8 values)

This is possible since all rows have the same structure thus all resulting arrays have the same of elements. We may see that as a large (10^8 x 300) matrix.

I have tried an aggregation using the $concatArrays but it failed due to the 16Mo limit of aggregations.

This my try considering one of the fields 'F' of the collection 'A'. Since the number of documents is too large, I decided to split the process into 500000 steps. I convert this part of the collection into one single collection 'F', with only one document.

```
outname = 'F';
step = 500000
count = db.A.count()

out = db[outname];
out.drop();
out.insert({F:[]});

op1 = {$arrayElemAt: [ '$x.F', 0 ]};
op2 = {$concatArrays: ['$F', op1]};

start = 0

for(i = 0; start < count; i++)
{
  tmp = 'tmp';
  db[tmp].drop();

  skip = start;

  print(i, skip, start);

  db.Object.aggregate( 
    [ 
      {$project: {'F': 1} }, 
      {$skip:    skip},
      {$limit:   step},
      {$group:   {'_id': '', 'F': {$push: '$F' } } }, 
      {$out:     tmp} 
    ], 
    {allowDiskUse: true} 
  );

  join = {$lookup: {'from': tmp, 'localField': outname + '._id', 'foreignField': tmp + '._id', 'as': 'x'} };
  out.aggregate( [ join, {'$project': {'F': op3} }, {'$out': outname} ], {allowDiskUse: true});

  start += step;
}
```

Of course the mechanism based on $concatArrays is not scalable.

How would you improve this? (I mean *efficiently* since those arrays are really huge)

Thanks for suggestions

Christian

Comment: It's not clear, why do you even keep using mongodb for this. 300 collections, each containing one array? Might as well just store the arrays in plain files.

Comment: Of course your comment is legitimate. I still want to make use of the Mongo's features (queries, aggregation,...). I simply observed that the current structure (row oriented) is not efficient since every search has to traverse the whole collection... except if I setup indexes (then time is fairly good). However I don't want to create 300 indexes (!!) which multiply by 6 the base size.!!!. Perhaps I'll recreate my base from raw data (which is possible in my use case)... I keep on searching...

Comment: Just to be clear, how do you plan to store data in those 300 collections? Document per value? Or all values in one/few documents? If it's the latter, then queries/aggregation might be diffucult to use. And for queries to be efficient in document-per-value scenario, you need 300 indexes anyway...

Comment: Precisely, my interrogation is about the best model. Originally data are provided as a large CSV file (10^8 lines of 300 items). My first attempt has been to create one big collection (10^8 documents each with 300 fields). This works well but only with indexes (of course). I wondered if another organisation might be better. (eg. 300 collections each with one array 10^8 values). Note also that this dataset will not change.

Comment: Immutable dataset of fixed (flat) structure records? This is, like, the ultimate anti-usecase for mongodb. Have you considered relational/columnar databases? Postgresql or vertica, for example?

Comment: Two features of Mongo are essential for us: 2D indexing and distributivity of the servers....